# Save the same instance twice in a transaction with updated values

Tags: java, multithreading, spring-boot, cron, transactions

I am writing a multithreaded cron job in Spring Boot. I have a list of users on which some action needs to be performed. Below is a snippet from by cron job

```
public void executeCronJob() {
    LOG.debug("Started >>>");
    User user = userService.findFirstNotInProgress();
    if (user == null) {
        LOG.debug("<<< User not found");
        return;
    }
    userService.updateStatus(user, Status.IN_PROGRESS);
    someOtherService.doSomeActionRelatedToUser(user);
    userService.updateStatus(user, Status.COMPLETED);
    LOG.debug("<<< Completed");
}
```

In **UserService.java**

```
private void updateStatus(User user, Status status) {
    user.setStatus(status);
    userRepository.save(user);
}
```

I am using multithreading because the `someOtherService.doSomeActionRelatedToUser(user);` method may take a considerable amount of time and hence block the execution for other users. The first call to `userService.updateStatus` works fine and the user enters in **IN_PROGRESS** status. But after performing the action on `someOtherService` related to the user, when I call `userService.updateStatus` again to set the status to **COMPLETED**, I get the error

> Row was updated or deleted by another transaction (or unsaved-value mapping was incorrect)

I have tried to user `userRepository.saveAndFlush(user);` in the UserService, but it still gives me the same error. How do I resolve this issue?

Comment: Looks like more than one thread trying to update the same entity, one thread succeeds and when the next thread goes to commit the data, it sees that its already been modified and ends up throwing the error.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to make sure that only one thread access the code block [given below] to fetch the user status and update the status to in progress. You have to synchronize the below block of code.

```
User user = userService.findFirstNotInProgress();
if (user == null) {
    LOG.debug("<<< User not found");
    return;
}
userService.updateStatus(user, Status.IN_PROGRESS);
```

Comment: Well that is the problem. I need multiple threads to access the given block of code, so that each thread can work on a different user. Shouldn't synchronization problem occur only when accessing the same instance of user?

Comment: You may only synchronise the block of code mentioned in my comment. That will make sure that the findFirstNotInProgress user is not read by multiple threads simultaneously. The doSomeActionRelatedToUser method will still be accessible to multiple threads

Answer (score 0):

You are passing `user` associated with the session to multiple threads and as  Hibernate Session objects are not thread-safe, you ending up with this error.

You can update the status to COMPLETED in `doSomeActionRelatedToUser()` with new session instead of from `executeCronJob()`.

Or you may want `someOtherService.doSomeActionRelatedToUser(user);` to return `CompletableFuture` and then update the status.

Hope it helps.